# problem wth fullcalendar timelineweek: spec.class is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, angular, fullcalendar

I am creating a calendar with fullcalendar, jquery-angular, but when adding

`defaultView: 'timelineWeek'`

I get this error:

> spec.class is not a constructor

either with `timelineweek`, `timelineday`, or any other. Also, if I include one of the timeline type in header, the button does not appear in the upper part either.

Comment: @DavidMakogon ok.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timeline-view), the timeline view types are only available if you include the [Scheduler add-on](https://fullcalendar.io/scheduler) in your page.

This is a commercial add-on to fullCalendar, so depending on your circumstances you may need to pay a license fee to use it. Again, check the documentation at the link above to determine what you need to if you want to use it.

Comment: I have add this " schedulerLicenseKey: 'CC-Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives'" , but the error persists, does it mean that I can not prove it works without first buying the license?

Comment: did you download and add the actual Scheduler _code_ to your solution as well as just setting the license key option?

Comment: yes, i add fullcalendar-scheduler with npm, and add this "node_modules/fullcalendar-scheduler/dist/scheduler.js" in angular.json.

Comment: No, no pude resolverlo, implemente un Full calendar customizado  completamente que el cliente nos proporciono.

Comment: Please write in English only. Most of us cannot understand you. Thanks.

Comment: translation of @NataliGamboa comment if any one wants : No, I could not solve it, I implemented a fully customized Full calendar that the client provided us